# Linking error for opencv 4.5.0 android-sdk on Pixel3a phone

Tags: android, opencv, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am trying to run an opencv sample on my android phone. But I cannot deploy as there are obviously missing some shared libraries.
I followed these instructions: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-opencv-library-into-android-application-using-android-studio/
But when running on the phone I get:

```
D/OpenCV/StaticHelper: Cannot load library "opencv_java4"
W/System.err: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc++_shared.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~LHITGOvV6k0oRByOAFyQmA==/com.example-0tIXMJKLKXWV7xxcppRycg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java4.so in namespace classloader-namespace
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
```

The .so files are present in the jniLibs folder... Could anybody help?
I have used the latest opencv android sdk...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the newest version of the opencv-android-sdk. In version 4.5.0 there are missing some .so files so I just switched back to an older version, now it works.